# Unable to install Mysql community server on Debian 10

Tags: mysql, debian-buster

Hi I am unable to install mysql 8 on my newly installed Debian 10 machine.
Here is what I did:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

After this ran 
$ sudo apt update
$ sudp apt  install mysql-server 


I am getting the bellow error: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.18-1debian10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if dependencies are available in debian 10 repo.
Try your luck with installing the dependencies with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```